# How do I fix the time issue in this code?

Tags: python, discord

I've been using this code on a discord bot in order to get it to produce the weather for the next 24 hours.

```
import requests
import discord

def get_weather(city, state, api_key):
    base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast"
    params = {
        "q": f"{city},{state}",
        "appid": api_key,
        "units": "imperial",
        "cnt": 9
    }

    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    data = response.json()

    # Check if the API request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Extract and format the weather information
        weather_info = []
        for forecast in data['list']:
            date_time = forecast['dt_txt']
            temperature = forecast['main']['temp']
            weather_description = forecast['weather'][0]['description']
            weather_info.append(f"{date_time}: {temperature}°F, {weather_description}")

        return weather_info
    else:
        return f"Error: {data['message']}"

api_key = ''
bot_token = ''
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("!weather"):
        await message.channel.send("Enter the state: ")

        def check_state(m):
            return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel

        state_msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check_state, timeout=60)
        state = state_msg.content

        await message.channel.send("Enter the city: ")

        def check_city(m):
            return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel

        city_msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check_city, timeout=60)
        city = city_msg.content

        weather_info = get_weather(city, state, api_key)

        if isinstance(weather_info, str):
            await message.channel.send(weather_info)
        else:
            await message.channel.send("\n".join(weather_info))

client.run(bot_token)
```

While it works and produces a result, the time is off. Giving a setting the time 6 hours ahead of the actual temperature at that time.

```
2023-07-05 00:00:00: 81.46°F, light rain
2023-07-05 03:00:00: 77.63°F, few clouds
2023-07-05 06:00:00: 72.77°F, clear sky
2023-07-05 09:00:00: 70.63°F, clear sky
2023-07-05 12:00:00: 76.95°F, clear sky
2023-07-05 15:00:00: 87.58°F, clear sky
2023-07-05 18:00:00: 93.49°F, few clouds
2023-07-05 21:00:00: 92.32°F, broken clouds
2023-07-06 00:00:00: 82.67°F, broken clouds
```

I got this, which would be the correct temperature if the time was set back 6 hours, any way I could fix this?

Comment: If that's your actual API key, you should probably change your password.

Comment: `openweathermap` doesn't know where you are.  It's delivering you time in UTC.  You need to compensate for your local time zone, which only YOU know.  You must be in central time zone.

Comment: fixxed the api stuff lol

Comment: https://www.datasciencelearner.com/convert-utc-to-local-time-python/

Comment: From the FAQ: *"Which time format and timezone are used?<br>
OpenWeather uses Unix time and the UTC/GMT time zone for all API calls, including current weather, forecast and historical weather data. The timezone_offset parameter shows the shift in seconds from UTC. In the One Call API 3.0 response, there is also a timezone parameter that shows the time zone name for the requested location."*

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to local time.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
...
        for forecast in data['list']:
            d1 = forecast['dt_txt']
            d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            d3 = d2.astimezone(tzlocal())
            date_time = d3.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```